# Spring Boot - How to create a custom serialization for " java.time.LocalDateTime" class

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, web, jackson

I have developed a rest service with Spring Boot. I want return a json response with the birthday of the user as milliseconds.
How to serialize a `java.time.LocalDateTime` object to milliseconds ?

My model class:

```
    @Entity(name = "users")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;



        @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
        private LocalDateTime dateOfBirth;  

 . . .

    }
```

current response:

```
{
 . . .
"dateOfBirth":[2018,7,25,7,0],
. . . 
}
```

preferred response:

```
{
 . . .
"dateOfBirth": 1532786354419,
. . . 
}
```

Comment: That should *not* be your preferred format. If you store as millis, you have to know the time zone as well in order to correctly deserialize it, because a given millis can be interpreted as many different LocalDateTimes. If it's really a LocalDateTime, store it in a timezone independent format; if it's really an instant in time, represent it as an instant in time.

Comment: Can't you just use java.util.Date instead since it stores it in millis? @jhontonini

Comment: i answered only use of custom serializer. now added time conversion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)`

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;


    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private LocalDateTime dateOfBirth;  

    . . .

}
```

custom serilizer class:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {
@Override
public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    //add your custom date parser
    gen.writeString(value.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()+"");
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to decorate all you objects with `@JsonSerialize` you can configure the object mapper to always return a long for `LocalDateTime`.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

and the de- and serializers.

```
public class LocalDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(String.valueOf(value.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond()));
    }
}

public class LocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long.parseLong(p.getValueAsString())), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

In your example you are using date of birth which could be a `LocalDate`.

Comment: My example does not convert to mills, but to Epoch Unix Time Stamp.

Answer (score -2):

Why dont you store date property as below :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date date = new Date();
```

It gives date in milliseconds. Formatting it to desired output is responsibility of application layer. Don't do it on entity itself with some annotation.